# Creating custom tags : optional binding

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets

I'm encountering problem with a custom tag.

Here's the problem. I created a  tag which is used in my JSF pages :

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core">

    ... some stuff ...

<h:inputText id="#{id}" value="#{value}" binding="#{binding}" label="#{label}"/>

    ... some stuff ...
</ui:composition>
```

I want to use this component in my pages in this way (my component is named gp:inputText) :

```
<gp:inputText value="#{myBean.myValue}" id="myId" label="myLabel" binding="#{myBean.myUiComponent}" />
```

But I also want to use the same component but without binding the inputText. How can I do that? 
I tried to just use my component without specifying the binding but it doaes not work. It seems that the binding value cannot be null like the label value for example.

Thanks for the help !

Comment: Use composite component. There you can map the binding attribute in a natural way.

Comment: I do not understand how the composite component can help me. The problem is that I do not understand what can be a default value for the binding attribute. JSF does not work for example if I write binding="" on a inputText. Therefore, I can write label="" and it can works...   Please can you explain me a little bit more how can I make this works with composite component ?

Comment: The binding attribute cannot have a "default" value. You bind the component to a bean property using the binding attribute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to define a binding attribute without a correct value.

However, you can avoid to define a binding attribute when it's null, like this :

```
<h:inputText id="#{id}" value="#{value}" label="#{label}">
    <c:if test="#{binding != null}" >
        <f:attribute name="binding" value="#{binding}" />
    </c:if>
</h:inputText>
```

Comment: Thanks. Just a little modification :
    <c:if test="#{binding != ''}">
and it works.

Comment: Rather use `#{not empty binding}`.

Comment: is the way of using binding working fine with `call/callback component update` using ajax for example? give me a tip pls